# nginx with tomcat is not working

Tags: nginx, tomcat7

My tomcat application is not being getting invoked by nginx.

Tomcat App working fine at: `http://localhost:8080/web/`

Nginx URL: `http://localhost/web`

nginx configuration:

```
location /web {
     proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080/web;
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;            
 }
```

Comment: posting nginx logs would definitely help, i feel that you might be missing `/` after `/web`

Comment: 2012/12/28 18:15:07 [error] 6572#3740: *16 CreateFile() "D:\Program Files\servers\nginx-1.3.1/html/inventoryflow" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /inventoryflow HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be something like:

```
location /web {
     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;            
     proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080;
}
```

Comment: It giving me 404 Not Found,

Comment: What nginx.conf do you have?. Nginx or Tomcat returns 404?. you checked the access.log?